# XPATH SQL identifier is too long

Tags: java, sql, xml, xpath, netbeans

I'm working with XPATH expressions using Java JDBC within Netbeans IDE. I have encountered this error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long, with the following query:

```
result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a.book.extract('/book/author/text()').getStringVal() "
                + "FROM BOOK a "
                + "WHERE a.book.existsNode(\"/book/title[contains(text(), 'Potter')]\") = 1 ");
        System.out.println("\n------------Query 8 Results------------");
        System.out.println("Authors of Books whose title contains 'Potter': \n");
        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println(result.getString(1));
        }//end while
```

Is there anyway around this without changing the names of tables etc. Thanks!

Comment: Can you figure out what "identifier" it thinks is too long? And is there a reason why you use single quotes for the first XPath expression and double quotes for the second? Are both syntactically valid here? What if you tried `a.book.existsNode('/book/title[contains(text(), \"Potter\")]')`?

Comment: That works perfect! thank you so much :)